# Finding values not in another dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

In SAS:I'm having 2 datasets & if I want to find out values of only variable which are not present in another dataset that's easy.

Now if I have to compare in the following way:

```
data dataset1;
input PointA $ PointB $ @6 date date7.;
format date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
NY LV 02Oct2018
NY LV 04Oct2018
NY LV 06Oct2018
;
```

which gives Dataset1:

```
Obs    PointA   PointB  Date
1      NY       LV      10/02/2002
2      NY       LV      10/04/2002
3      NY       LV      10/06/2002
```

Dataset2 has dates from 01Oct2018 to 06Oct2018.

```
DATE
01Oct2018
02Oct2018
03Oct2018
04Oct2018
05Oct2018
06Oct2018
```

WANTED: The final output i want is which all values (dates) in Dataset1 are absent for PointA-PointB as compared to Dataset2. So my desired output is:

```
Obs   PointA   PointB   Date
1      NY       LV      10/01/2002
2      NY       LV      10/03/2002
3      NY       LV      10/05/2002
```

I'm using NOT IN but it gives me only the dates. Somehow I need to include the other variables; in this case PointA, PointB.

Comment: your description is confusing, but what is that you are comparing(only dates or any other corresponding values). how does your second dataset look like. what is the code you have tested.

Comment: I'm comparing only dates... have edited my question

Comment: your dataset1 will have only one destination or multiple destination, then what happens data dataset1;
input PointA $ PointB $ @6 date date7.;
format date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
NY LV 02Oct2018
NY LV 04Oct2018
NY LV 06Oct2018
CS LA 01Oct2018
CS LA 03Oct2018
CS LA 05Oct2018
;

Comment: Why input with `date7.` when the date representation in the datalines is `date9.` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a full cartesian join with `ON` criteria involving a not equal (`ne`) comparison. Remove the original 'have' rows from the cartesian with an `EXCEPT` set-operator

```
* use the proper informat! ;
data have;
input PointA $ PointB $ date date9.; format date mmddyy10.; datalines;
NY LV 02Oct2018
NY LV 04Oct2018
NY LV 06Oct2018
;

data dates; input
date date9.; format date mmddyy10.; datalines;
01Oct2018
02Oct2018
03Oct2018
04Oct2018
05Oct2018
06Oct2018
;

proc sql;
  create table have_not_lookup as
  select distinct 
    have.PointA, have.PointB, lookup.date
  from 
    have
  join 
    dates lookup 
  on 
    lookup.date NE have.date
  except
    select * from have
  ;
```